# Firefox iframe scrolling issue

Tags: javascript, firefox, iframe, scroll

I have a web page that is hosted in an iframe.  I can only modify this page and not the containing page.

By default, my page's scrollbar is disabled, however if my page's size is over a certain threshold, I need to be able to turn on the vertical scrollbar.  The following code seems to work in all browsers but Firefox:

```
function getDocHeight() {
    var D = document;
    return Math.max(
        Math.max(D.body.scrollHeight, D.documentElement.scrollHeight),
        Math.max(D.body.offsetHeight, D.documentElement.offsetHeight),
        Math.max(D.body.clientHeight, D.documentElement.clientHeight)
    );
}

function setScrollbar() {
    if (getDocHeight() > 5000) {
        pageBody.style.overflow = 'scroll';
    }
}
```

here is my HTML:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
    <head><title>My title</title></head>
    <body id="pageBody" onload="setScrollbar();">
    </body>
</html>
```

Firefox seems to be ignoring the style.overflow = 'scroll'.  I've done a good bit of searching, and I can't seem to find a solution.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
pageBody.style.overflow = 'scroll';
```

with this:

```
document.getElementById('pageBody').style.overflow = 'scroll';
```

When I've checked your code in FF I was getting JS error pageBody is undefined, that should solve the issue :)

Cheers

G.

Answer (score 0):

`style.overflow = 'auto'` should work better. It makes the browser decide when to add scroll bars itself.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Firefox displays the scrollbars on the body of a frame based on the overflow style on the frame, not on the body. So the easiest way is to insert a 100% size borderless scrollable subframe, and load the real content in there instead.

If you don't want to do that, then you can mess around with nested DIVs like this:

```
<body style="margin: 0px;"> <!-- override default body margin -->
  <div style="height: 100%; overflow: auto;"> <!-- The actual scrollable area -->
    <div style="margin: 8px;"> <!-- to emulate default body margin -->
      <!-- Content goes here -->
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```